# Are old unused Stack Exchange 1.0 sites ever going to be closed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-exchange

In [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/) blog post, it was said that communities that don't prosper will be closed in order to prevent fragmentation of the community and to draw attention to other sites.

Browsing through the computers section of the [master Stack Exchange 1.0 list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites), I see multiple sites that have less than 50 questions and all are ghost towns. For example (all statistics as of this post):

- [Coverflow](http://coverflowexchange.com/questions) - 21 questions
- [fmoverflow](http://fmoverflow.net/questions) - 10(!) questions
- [Gamestruction](http://www.gamestruction.com/questions) (dupe of one in Area 51 anyway) - 37 questions
- [4xPDF](http://help.4xpdf.com/questions) - 112 questions, but that's from over 8 months and is very inactive
- [mesa de ayuda](http://www.mesadeayuda.org/questions)(?) - 42 questions
- [Packetdrop](http://www.packetdrop.net/questions) - 15(!) questions

That's only a few of the sites that are graveyards, and that's only in the computer section! These niche communities only exist to draw people away from other sites, which is bad.

Now I know that these people paid a lot of money for these sites. But couldn't you give them a refund of some kind? I don't think we should bully the sites out of existence, but if you remove 75% of them (and I'm hoping that most will voluntarily go), the master list above will actually be useful, instead of a bunch of links to various dead sites.

Comment: They may have paid for WordArt logos, but they didn't pay anyone at SO, inc for those ghost towns.

Comment: Wasn't that the business model of SE 1.0: Hand over $150(?) and you can get a new site?

Comment: They never lasted long enough for SE 1.0 to start charging and before the VC money.

Comment: Here's the blog entry btw: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/

Comment: More like put out of their misery.

Comment: @random, I'm confused.  The blog entry reads "However, by setting a price ($129-$5000/month, depending on traffic) to cover the cost of servers and bandwidth, we discouraged a lot of people from making sites that might have been great."  Are you saying they announced but never collected those server/bandwidth fees from anyone?

Comment: The monthly costs were part of SE1.0 after a certain beta period for each proposal. They never really went past the beta to start collecting on the fees.

Comment: @random: Ah, thats why you all have been saying you never made any money. Thanks for that, I was really getting confused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of those sites have *already* expired (i.e. they are scheduled for removal). We will have to remove them *soon* for technical reason but we are in no rush to do so.

We are keeping them up as long as we can out of *consideration* for all the users who have contributed content — content that those users can save on the newer sites as they come online. Until then, site owners and users are backing up their content and making other arrangements.

As for "special treatment," how many SE 2.0 sites have been deleted? And nobody "paid a lot of money for these sites." Stack Exchange never collected any money for hosting sites.

Comment: So they are going to get deleted, just not right now because of the amount of contributed content. That makes sense. And the reason I said they cost money was because of the blog post. However random relieved in a comment above that they only cost money if they got out of the beta state, which none did.

Answer (score 2):

How are they distracting from the SOFO/SE/Area51 community? They're **inactive** so clearly nobody is going to them. If they were distracting our communities they would be bustling with activity.

Comment: You have people there that occasionally ask questions, meaning they are only partially inactive. But as per the blog post, inactive = deleted for SE 2.0. So why do SE 1.0 sites get special treatment?

Comment: @Lord, because they signed up under a different set of rules.

Answer (score 2):

Both [fogbugz.stackexchange.com](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/) and [kiln.stackexchange.com](http://kiln.stackexchange.com/) are closing because

> as of September 1, 2013, Stack Exchange, the operator of the forum,
>   will be shutting down the site.

So apparently, yes.

Or as explained on their [new platform](http://help.fogcreek.com/about):

> The Stack Exchange team decided that it was time to
>   decommission all of these old servers and let us know we would have to
>   move to a new site by the end of the summer (2013). We were
>   disappointed by the news...

Comment: Wellllllll, they won't be on SE 1.0 anymore, but those particular ones will be moving to their own platform.

Comment: @NickCraver interesting, but that's what Derrick told me...